# define open sector and closed sector in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

Let us define open sector and closed sector in complex plane respectively by $\{z : \alpha<arg(z)<\beta \}$ and $ \{z: \alpha\leq arg(z)\leq \beta \}$, where $ 0<\alpha-\beta\leq 2 \pi$.

Consider the following transcendental functions:

$$ f(z)=e^z \cos z \ \ \text{and} \ \ g(z)=\frac{e^z \cos z}{z}$$

In which sectors, if any, do these functions decay to $0$ as $z \to \infty$ ?

**Answer:**

If $z<0$, then both the functions decays to $0$, otherwise not.

But I think $z$ can not be negative according to the given condition $ 0<\alpha-\beta\leq 2 \pi$.

So how to solve it.

Help me

Comment: You have a typo: an open sector is defined as $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : \alpha < \text{arg}(z) < \beta\}$ and similarly for closed sector.

Comment: What do you mean by $z<0$ for a nonreal $z\in\mathbb{C}$?